# Binding for ComboBox Header in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a WPF MVVM pattern application, and I am trying to use a combo box in the header to filter the grid.  I can do this when all of the code is in the Window class (not MVVM) but for my own sake I am trying to bind it to the VM to get the same results.  Here's the XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="transNameColumn" Binding="{Binding TransName}" Width="325">
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding oTran}" DisplayMemberPath="TransName" SelectedValuePath="UID"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="315">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Transmittal_ComboSelect}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

The DataGrid in which this resides looks like this (just the top where the binding is):

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="transNameColumn" Binding="{Binding TransName}" Width="325">
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding oTran}" DisplayMemberPath="TransName" SelectedValuePath="UID"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="315">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Transmittal_ComboSelect}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

and the top level grid is bound thusly:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
```

I am thinking that because the combo box is inside the datagrid the binding gets messed up.  When I have the combo box on its own, with the same XAML it works fine.  But when inserted as the header it does not populate (and I think the event binding will also not work, but can't verify as it does not populate so there's no way to make a selection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use RelativeSource in your binding. It will end up looking something like this:

```
"{Binding DataContext.oTran, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that back.  I think in previous steps I had removed that line (when porting from the non MVVM into the MVVM version).  I am slowly beginning to understand what the DataContext is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to kelly suggestion. Refer the complete code for adding combobox column.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgr" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                           
                        <TextBlock Text="combo" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="cboBhp" 
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboItems, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.ComboValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                            Mode=TwoWay}">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
public class GridSample
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}


public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string comboValue;
    public string ComboValue
    {
        get { return comboValue; }
        set
        {
            if (comboValue != value)
            {
                comboValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboValue");
            }
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        ComboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ComboItems.Add("pascal");
        ComboItems.Add("Braye");

        ComboValue = "pascal";

        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridSample>() {
        new GridSample() { Name = "Jim"} ,new GridSample() { Name = "Adam"} };

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string str)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GridSample> GridItems { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent detail in code . . . even when I end up having everything set up right, it's always good to see other approaches and styles.  And it's rare that I'm not seeing another mistake in my thinking when seeing another example set up.